# class 'Parser' does not implement the 'NSXMLParserDelegate' protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I just downloaded the code from http://cocoadevblog.com/iphone-tutorial-creating-a-rss-feed-reader to see how to implement rss feeder And it shows a warning " class 'Parser' does not implement the 'NSXMLParserDelegate' protocol " at [rssParser setDelegate:self]; in parer.m. App loads in simulator but does not work. I checked in refernces foundation is included. Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are building for iOS 4, make sure your interface looks like this:

```
 @protocol NSXMLParserDelegate; //makes sure it builds in previous versions of iOS.
 @interface Parser<NSXMLParserDelegate> {
 ...
 }
 ...
 @end
```

That said, this is just a warning. If your code is correct, it should work.

Comment: was about to post similar thing - was too slow
+1 though ;)